# open an ssh tunnel from heroku python app on the cedar stack?

Tags: python, ssh, heroku, paramiko, cedar

Is it possible to open a non-blocking ssh tunnel from a python app on the heroku cedar stack? I've tried to do this via paramiko and also asyncproc with no success.

On my development box, the tunnel looks like this:

ssh -L local_port:remote_server:remote_port another_remote_server

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post the STDERR of `ssh -v -L .....`? May be you need to disable the tty allocation and run ssh in batch mode.

Answer (score 0):

This recipe ought to work with Python (even though it was for a Rails app).  Here's the recipe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27361295/558639

The biggest challenge is convincing ssh to not prompt when it starts up.