# SSH tunneling from Heroku

Tags: heroku, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm providing a service hosted on Heroku which lets users report on their own data, using their database. My customers have to connect my Heroku app to their database. Some of them are obviously afraid of letting data transit in clear over the Internet.

Is it possible with Heroku to open an SSH tunnel from my app (Play Framework/Java) to their machines?

NB: I'm aware of [SSH tunneling to a remote DB from Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917883/ssh-tunneling-to-a-remote-db-from-heroku) but on that question, using the built-in Heroku db was possible.

Thank you,
Adrien

Comment: Why would you need an ssh tunnel? If they are concerned about data being transmitted "in the clear", simply have your database connect over ssl. All DBs (well, major DBs) support that.

Comment: Thanks @NitzanShaked, 1. Customers feel more confident that no data will leak, 2. It allows to bypass some firewalls, 3. With Oracle, from what I read, it's hard to be sure we're always using the encrypted one, 4. Without a tunnel, anyone else from the internet can try to brute-force the connection, whereas with a tunnel, it has to come from me.

Comment: All the reasons you mention are valid, no doubt. My point is that using an ssl connection string (for Oracle, for MySQL, whatever) solved the problem just as well. I am not sure what "hardships" there are with Oracle, but I am sure they can be overcome. If you are absolutely set on using a tunnel, then it can be done of course -- just run ssh -L <db_port>:<db_name>:<db_port>, where <db_name> is the name of your client's db server *as seen from the machine you are sshing into*, and have your code connect to localhost:<db_port>.

Comment: You could transform this into a real answer. So ssh -L will open a new port on the Heroku machine (for 127.0.0.1 access only), is that permitted? It seems it isn't, if you search for the word 'loopback' on that page: https://www.heroku.com/policy/security - Do I understand the page well?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

### Yes, you can.

Having now gone down this path: yes, it **is** possible to set up an SSH tunnel from heroku to an external database.  [NOTE: My particular app was written in Ruby on Rails, but the solution given here should work for any language hosted on Heroku.]

### Statement of the problem

I am running an app on Heroku.  The app needs to access an external MySQL database (hosted on AWS) from which it grabs data for analysis.  Access to the MySQL database is protected by ssh keys, i.e. you cannot access it with a password: you need an ssh key pair.  Since Heroku starts each dyno fresh, how can you set up an SSH tunnel with the proper credentials?

### Short Answer

Create a script file, say ssh_setup.sh.  Put it in ${HOME}/.profile.d/ssh_setup.sh.  Heroku will notice any file in ${HOME}/.profile.d and execute it when it creates your dyno.  Use the script file to set up ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and then launch ssh in tunneling mode.

### The Full Recipe

#### 1. Generate keypair for access to the external DB

Create a key pair and save it in ~/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa and ~/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa.pub.  Use an empty passphrase (otherwise the Heroku dyno will try to prompt for it when it starts up):

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "me@example.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/.ssh/id_rsa): /home/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa.pub.
```

#### 2. Test ssh access to the external DB

Send your PUBLIC key (~/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa.pub) to the administrator for the external DB and ask for access using that key.  After that, you should be able to type the following into a shell window on your local machine:

```
$ ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa -N -L 3307:${REMOTE_MYSQL_HOST}:3306 ${TUNNEL_USER}@${TUNNEL_SITE}
```

where

- ${REMOTE_MYSQL_HOST} is the address of the remote database.  In our case, it is something like long_complicated_string.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
- ${TUNNEL_USER} is the user account on the site that accesses the database
- ${TUNNEL_SITE} is the address of the machine that accesses the database

You should get a long string of debugging output that include the following:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
...
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

Congratulations.  You've set up tunneling on your own machine to the external database.  Now to convince Heroku to do the same...

#### 3. Set up configuration variables

The goal is to copy the contents of ~/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa and ~/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa.pub to the corresponding directories on your Heroku dyno whenever it starts up, but you REALLY don't want to expose your private key in a script file.

Instead, we'll use Heroku's configuration variables, which simply (and safely) sets up shell environment variables when launching the dyno.

```
$ heroku config:set HEROKU_PRIVATE_KEY=`cat ~/.ssh/heroku_rsa_id`
$ heroku config:set HEROKU_PUBLIC_KEY=`cat ~/.ssh/heroku_rsa_id.pub`
```

While we're at it, we'll set up a few other potentially sensitive variables as well:

```
$ heroku config:set REMOTE_MYSQL_HOST=<your value of REMOTE_MYSQL_HOST from above>
$ heroku config:set TUNNEL_USER=<your value of TUNNEL_USER from above>
$ heroku config:set TUNNEL_SITE=<your value of TUNNEL_SITE from above>
```

#### 4. Create version 1.0 of your script file

In your project home directory, create a directory .profile.d.  In that directory, create the following:

```
# file: .profile.d/ssh-setup.sh

#!/bin/bash
echo $0: creating public and private key files

# Create the .ssh directory
mkdir -p ${HOME}/.ssh
chmod 700 ${HOME}/.ssh

# Create the public and private key files from the environment variables.
echo "${HEROKU_PUBLIC_KEY}" > ${HOME}/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa.pub
chmod 644 ${HOME}/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa.pub

# Note use of double quotes, required to preserve newlines
echo "${HEROKU_PRIVATE_KEY}" > ${HOME}/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa
chmod 600 ${HOME}/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa

# Preload the known_hosts file  (see "version 2" below)

# Start the SSH tunnel if not already running
SSH_CMD="ssh -f -i ${HOME}/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa -N -L 3307:${REMOTE_MYSQL_HOST}:3306 ${REMOTE_USER}@${REMOTE_SITE}"

PID=`pgrep -f "${SSH_CMD}"`
if [ $PID ] ; then
    echo $0: tunnel already running on ${PID}
else
    echo $0 launching tunnel
    $SSH_CMD
fi
```

#### 5. Push the configuration and test it on Heroku

You know the drill...

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'launching ssh when Heroku dyno starts up'
$ git push heroku master
```

Give it a whirl...

```
$ heroku run sh
```

You may see something like:

```
Running `sh` attached to terminal... up, run.1926
bash: creating public and private key files
bash: launching tunnel
The authenticity of host 'example.com (11.22.33.44)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 1f:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

This is a problem, since it means the dyno needs user input to continue.  But we're about to fix that.  What follows is a somewhat ugly hack, but it works.  (If someone has a better solution, please comment!)

#### 6. Create version 2.0 of your script file

(Continuing from above) Answer `yes` to the prompt and let the script run to completion.  We're now going to capture the output of the known_hosts file:

```
heroku $ cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts
|1|longstringofstuff= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 more stuff=
|1|morestuff= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 yetmorestuff=
```

Copy that output and paste it into your ssh-setup.sh file under the "Preload the known_hosts" comment, and edit so it looks like this:

```
# Preload the known_hosts file  (see "version 2" below)
echo '|1|longstringofstuff= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 more stuff=
|1|morestuff= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 yetmorestuff=' > ${HOME}/.ssh/known_hosts

# Start the SSH tunnel if not already running
... etc ...
```

#### 7. Push and test v2

You know the drill...

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'preload known_hosts file to avoid prompt'
$ git push heroku master
```

Give it a whirl.  With luck, you should see something like this:

```
$ heroku run sh
Running `sh` attached to terminal... up, run.1926
bash: creating public and private key files
bash: launching tunnel
```

#### 8. Debugging

If the tunnel isn't getting set up properly, try pre-pending a -v (verbose) argument to the SSH command in the script file:

```
SSH_CMD="ssh -v -f -i ${HOME}/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa -N -L ${LOCAL_PORT}:${REMOTE_MYSQL_HOST}:${MYSQL_PORT} ${REMOTE_USER}@${REMOTE_SITE}"
```

Repeat the `git add ... git commit ... git push` sequence and call `heroku run sh`.  It will print a lot of debug output.  A sysadmin friend with more brains than I have should be able to decode that output to tell you where the problem lies.

#### 9. (Rails only): Configuring the DB

If you're running Rails, you'll need a way to access the database within your Rails app, right?  Add the following to your `config/database.yml` file (changing the names appropriate):

```
mysql_legacy:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: mysql_legacy
  username: <%= ENV['LEGACY_DB_USERNAME'] || 'root' %>
  password: <%= ENV['LEGACY_DB_PASSWORD'] || '' %>
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3307
```

The important thing to note is that the host is the local host (127.0.0.1) and the port (3307) must match the -L argument given to ssh in the script:

```
-L 3307:${REMOTE_MYSQL_HOST}:3306
```

### In summary

Despite what's been said elsewhere, you can tunnel out of Heroku to access a remote database.  The above recipe makes a LOT of assumptions, but with some customizations it should work for your specific needs.

Now I'll go get some sleep...

Comment: Thanks, your recipe is working for me ! You have a small typo in the script though: `s/REMOTE_USER/TUNNEL_USER/` and `s/REMOTE_SITE/TUNNEL_SITE/`. Also you could mention autossh for more reliable ssh tunnels.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Two possible improvements: 1) One issue with using an ssh tunnel for mysql is that they often drop, using [autossh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh) will auto-reconnect for you.  There is already a [heroku build pack](https://github.com/kollegorna/heroku-buildpack-autossh) for it.  2) You can work around the known hosts issue by using `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you!. It inspired me to write a full and detailed guide - specific to running Metabase (an awesome free BI reporting app) on Heroku, but which anyone can easily follow for their own app needs: https://github.com/rmcsharry/metabase-deploy/blob/master/heroku_guide.md

Comment: @PatrickBrowne I am trying to use this to connect to an AWS EC2 instance, and I'm having trouble making a connection to localhost:<forwarding_port> and I think it has to do with Heroku's policy on loopback network interface (i.e., no connecting to localhost, if I understand it correctly). How did you get around that?

Comment: It's been a long time since I tried and I no longer use that technique. I do not think Heroku had that policy at that time so I cannot help you I am sorry :/

Comment: Nice answer, you could avoid the user interaction by using ssh-keyscan and putting the result in the known_hosts file as in `ssh-keyscan -t rsa <REMOTE_MYSQL_HOST> > ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: @JimmyKnoot: That's a great improvement.  Since I'm no longer running a Heroku project, If you (or anybody) is in a position to test that and edit the answer, the community would thank you!