# Set config variables in heroku using `cat example.file`

Tags: bash, heroku, environment-variables

I'm following this tutorial (best answer) [SSH tunneling from Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575582/ssh-tunneling-from-heroku/27361295#27361295)

And they say to set some heroku config vars like MY_VAR=`cat my.file` to save the contents of the file to heroku. The problem is, I don't think this method works anymore. I'm looking for help on either how to do this the right way, or how to emulate this. Here is the traceback.

```
(bosnetvenv) michael@michael-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-MJ401TA:~/projects/znet/bosnet$ heroku config:set ZEAL_FULL_NODE_PRIVATE_KEY=`cat ~/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa`
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.35.0 to 7.38.1.
 ▸    RSA is invalid. Must be in the format FOO=bar.
(bosnetvenv) michael@michael-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-MJ401TA:~/projects/znet/bosnet$ heroku config
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.35.0 to 7.38.1.
=== zealchain Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:              REDACTED
IS_PRODUCTION:              True
ZEAL_FULL_NODE_PRIVATE_KEY: 
(bosnetvenv) michael@michael-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-MJ401TA:~/projects/znet/bosnet$ heroku config:set ZEAL_FULL_NODE_PUBLIC_KEY=`cat ~/.ssh/heroku_id_rsa.pub`
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.35.0 to 7.38.1.
 ▸    REDACTED
 ▸    is invalid. Must be in the format FOO=bar.
```

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

needed quotes.

heroku config:set "MY_VAR=`test.file`"